# Neo4j would I need repeated nodes or can I reuse the same ones?

Tags: database, search, neo4j, tree, cypher

I've been tasked with looking into Neo4j for our business needs. I've created some very small graphs to get used to the cypher syntax.

We have a scenario where a user will be able to search via many options which will need to then need to show their related data and keep track of these available items in stock as the results are filtered down. As a simple example (but the same design as what we will need). We might have 4 items of clothing (T-shirt, sweater, jeans, shirt) and the user can select either one to reveal their sizes and colours etc and keep track of the number in stock. However the user should be able to select size or colour first instead to reveal the different items (t-shirt,jeans etc). Basically different combinations depending on what is selected.

Jeans (20 in stock) > red (6) > small (2) or large (4),  Jeans > green > small or large, Small > red > t-shirts, shirts, Green > large > t-shirts

In this scenario would the colour and size nodes need to be repeated for each items or could I just create them once and reuse them? This is the thing I am a little confused about. We will have potentially 150+ (list of countries) choices for one option node and if each one has its own unique nodes related to it (but are repeated for other options as new nodes) that is a lot of duplicates? We could have a million plus nodes...

Sorry if this is a dumb question! Just trying to gather if there is a particular way of handling this kind of use case in Neo4j.

Thank you very much for your help and advice. :)

Answer (score 2):

In essence, this problem can be traced back to the good old attributes vs. entities question in ER modeling

1. Using separate entites. Creating singleton nodes for colors, sizes, country etc. seems a working solution and you can reuse them for multiple items. For example, if you want to assign red color to an item `n`, you'd issue this query: `MATCH (r:Color {name: 'red'} CREATE (n)-[:HAS_COLOR]->(r)`. To select all red nodes, use `MATCH (n:Item)-[:HAS_COLOR]->(:Color {name: 'red'})`. This approach makes is easy to select all available colors, e.g. `MATCH (c:Color) RETURN DISTINCT c`
2. Using attributes. Using properties should also work fine. Filtering is even easier (`MATCH (:Item {color: 'red')`) and listing available colors can be implemented with `MATCH (n) RETURN DISTINCT n.color`

In conclusion, as with most data modeling questions, you'll probably need to go through a couple of iterations to get the data model right and maybe do some benchmarking/performance tuning as well. Fortunately, Neo4j makes it very easy to experiment with different data models.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! So I could effectively have a Country  node with all the different countries as attributes? I.e. CREATE (country:COUNTRY { uk: "UK", usa: "USA, france: "France" }) and so on? If I did this with all nodes and their respective attributes this would certainly keep the data model more concise! Basically our app will be filtering these results dynamically when options are selected so it needs to be as fast as we can get it.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use a node with properties as an enumeration? That would work on paper, but it's definitely not good practice. What would be the advantage of this? (over storing these as an enumeration in, let's say, Java code).

Comment: I think our team are trying to keep things simple due to our lack of knowledge of Neo4j but we certainly don't want to follow a bad design. I guess my idea was for the attributes to match the options the user could select in the app? I.e. if the user selects the country UK then we would do a MATCH on that and keep adding to the query as the user selects more options (color, item, size etc) but I'm not sure what the performance implications would be. We want to filter results down by doing a tree traversal and then query our MemSQL database at the end to retrieve the detailed data.

Comment: The property graph model of Neo4j allows you to store arrays, so you can create a list of available languages with `CREATE (:Countries {countries: ['UK', 'USA', 'France']})`. I am not sure about the usefulness of this though - ideally, this should not be in the database.

Comment: Querying along a tree is an interesting thought, as this is essentially an index that can be stored in a graph database (if required because of performance reasons). However, to make it work, users will have to follow the exact same steps for all items (e.g. size first, color next, etc.). It this realistic for your use case?

Comment: Well the size, colour, type etc could be selected in random orders. It could be size > colour >type, colour > type > size etc. With our data set we have 16 different entities and some of these have a hundred plus possible values to select from (country is one example). We would want to keep track of the number of results after each selection up/down the tree. I.e. there are 40 types of jean after selecting the type and then 23 after the size small is selected etc and keep updating this. However the user might reset the type selection so we just want everything in size small.

Comment: What's puzzling me is that this seems a textbook relational database use case. What are the graph-specific features that you'd like to use? To put it another way, what are you expecting from using a graph database - less redundancy, more concise queries, performance, ...?

Comment: That's actually a very valid point. If we have say 400,000 total results possible, then when it gets filtered down it has to dynamically update the results that match the options selected by the user (so after jeans > small > red there might be a total of 50 results found) then the user can click "Search" and the results are returned (from MemSQL) and rendered in a FlatList using React Native. Neo4j is purely for the search so the results (e.g. 55 found) are returned almost instantaneously. Could a RDBMS (e.g.Memsql) provide similar performance in returning the results?

Comment: It's difficult to answer this without the actual data set and queries, but based on the information available, I see no reason why it would not work. Also, in general, RDBMSs are a lot more tunable than NoSQL systems, so if your queries are not very graph-y, you can improve the performance a lot by tinkering with indexes, data modeling and database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There's often many ways to create your data model, and you'll have to weigh the pros and cons and figure out what may work best.

One aspect of consideration, attributes (properties) vs entities, Gabor covers in good detail.

Another aspect, just considering entities, is whether you want to use a tree structure, drilling down to a specific item whose attributes are defined by the nodes above it in the tree, or

For example, you might have a tree like this:

```
(jeans:Clothing:Attribute{type:'jeans'})-[:COLOR]->(jeansColor:Color:Attribute{type:'red'})
(jeansColor)-[:SIZE]->(:Size:Attribute{type:'small'})-[:QUANTITY]->(:Stock{quantity:2})
(jeansColor)-[:SIZE]->(:Size:Attribute{type:'large'})-[:QUANTITY]->(:Stock{quantity:4})
```

In this model each successive node in the hierarchy only has a single parent. The :Color node with type 'red' would only be applicable to the :Clothing node for 'jeans', and there would be other :Color nodes for 'red' in different hierarchies for different types of clothing. Similarly, :Size nodes would only have meaning within their hierarchy, so the 'small' and 'large' sizes above would only be applicable to red jeans, and the :Stock nodes would be specific to the hierarchy as well. We're using a second label :Attribute on :Color and :Size nodes so we can address those nodes more generically if we want.

Queries for stock at each level would use variable-length relationships down to :Item nodes and sum the quantities like so:

```
MATCH (:Clothing{type:'jeans'})-[*]->(item:Item)
RETURN sum(item.quantity) as stock
```

Queries for type would work the other direction (note we can use the :Attribute label instead of :Color here if we wanted):

```
MATCH (:Color{type:'red'})<-[*]-(clothing:Clothing)
RETURN collect(distinct clothing.type) as clothing
```

This model requires fairly rigid trees, and many duplicated nodes (as nodes with the same properties need to be duplicated across different branches of the trees).

An alternate model to consider is one where the attribute nodes (:Clothing, Color, :Size, and so on) have relationships directly with the related item, so each item is connected to all attributes which apply to it, similar to point 1 in Gabor's answer.

In this model, there is only one of each attribute node, so you won't have to deal with node duplication, but as the number of items in your db get larger, the work done in your matches might get more complicated, since you would be looking for item nodes at the intersection of all the items connected to the attributes you're searching for (so to find small red jeans you would expand to all items from each of the small, red, and jean attribute nodes and only keep the ones that are common between the three).